# Find a string in the column and active application Go to

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a string that will be always on the Row 3 but any column in a specific sheet, after the code find it the application GoTo should take the user to this column. However, I am having trouble with my code, maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub Pivot1()

    Dim SearchString As String
Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
Dim FirstFound As String
Dim sh As Worksheet

' Set Search value
SearchString = "Nr. 1"
Application.FindFormat.Clear

With Sheets("Analysis").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set cl = .Find(What:=SearchString, After:=Range("A:FA"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then Application.Goto cl
       End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: `With Sheets("Analysis").rows(3)` - you are searching one cell. In fact probably not a valid range.

Comment: And remove the `after` parameter.

Comment: @SJR thank you, it is working, However, maybe do you know why in this case I dont need `after`??

Comment: `After` is a single cell where to start the search within the specified search range. The search will start "after" that cell, loop through the search range and find a match in that cell last. Since you are searching a very small range it doesn't matter where you start, and since you don't know in which column the search will end it doesn't matter in which column you start the search, either.